# How to encrypt and decrypt data using in sending and receiving via TCP client

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, tcpclient

Im trying to develop a simple Server/client chat app, which the server is my own pc.
this app supports voice chat ( and maybe video chat in future! ) and I really want my transferring data be safe and unreadable by others.
I know that I should use SSL stream but purchasing certificates is impossible for me.
so I try to use System.Security.cryptography classes.
I found this walkthrough at link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172831.aspx.
but the problem is the encrypted data is much bigger than plain data and I dont think this is a good Idea for sending them via TCP clients. So what way is ideal one? which encryption algorithm is the best?
Do I need to purchase certs. anyway?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will try the GCM mode, Can I ask you for more help if I encounter any problem?

Comment: GCM provides authenticity (message integrity) in addition to confidentiality. However, using raw cryptography primitives will likely result in something bad unless you really know what you're doing. TLS with your own certificates is probably your best option.

Comment: @ntoskrnl is right, and I meant CTR mode for just confidentality as well. Unfortunately I'm not directly available for consultation.

Comment: Thank you guys I dont know much about cryptography but I will try TLS and CTR mode. thanks again